# Compiled file tells makefile how to compile

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

What I am asking might sound illogical but it is very important for me.

Lets assume we have such file and folders

```
project_rat/
project_cat/
project_rabbit/
Makefile
```

The user might add any project folder here. The `Makefile` has the following config  variable:

```
model_name:= project_rat
```

The user might change this `model_name`variable to any of the folders.

and the makefile compiles the appropriate project folder.

```
g++ -std=c++11 $(model_name)/main.cpp
```

Now my problem is that I want to add a debug/release variable into the `Makefile` and based on that I turn on the appropriate optimizer. I want this variable be determined from my project. It must depend on each individual project. One project might need `-O2` and the other `-O3`.

Can I influence `Makefile` from any C++ code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you're using GNU make (a safe bet, given your usage of gcc), add this to your `Makefile`:

```
include $(model_name)/Makefile.opts
```

Now, create a file `Makefile.opts` in each project directory, that sets the Makefile options for that project.

This works just like the C/C++ `#include` preprocessor directive.

If you do not want to require a `Makefile.opts` in each project directory, use `sinclude` instead of `include`.